# Powershell - delete folder if exists in an other directory

Tags: powershell, compare

I have folders in"Directory1" and zip of these folders in "Directory2" with the mention "_OK" at the end of the zip name.

**Directory1** : [image: Directory1] 1B002955_SML 23_LEAP 1A version2 mars2022_2022-03-11T08h00m40s_s603575

**Directory2** : [image: Directory2]1B002955_SML 23_LEAP 1A version2 mars2022_2022-03-11T08h00m40s_s603575_OK

Now i want to delete the folders from the 1st directory if the corresponding zip exists in the 2nd directory. The two directory aren't on the same server.

I thought about renaming Directory2 zip by removing "_OK"

```
rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_OK", "")
```

Then compare Directory1 and Directory2 with the compare-object cmdlet but I found that it's for comparing the specified properties and in my case I just want to compare names

Still new to powershell, i'm not sure the best way to proceed

Hope someone can help

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet as follows, assuming that:

- `$filesA` contains the [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)instances representing the folders to potentially delete,
- and `$fileeB` the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances representing the corresponding ZIP files,

as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) calls:

```sh
Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -PassThru $filesA $filesB -Property { 
    $_.BaseName -replace '_OK$'
  } | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq == | 
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- `-IncludeEqual` makes `Compare-Object` also include objects that compare the same (by default, only *differing* objects are reported).
- `-PassThru` causes the *LHS* input object from a pair of matching objects to be output (by default, only the matching *property value* - as defined by the `-Property` argument(s) - is output.)
- `-Property { $_.BaseName -replace '_OK$' }` uses a nameless [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to compare pairs of input objects by; in this case, the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator is used to effectively remove string `_OK`, if present at the end (`$`), from the base file name (the file name without extension).
- [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)  `SideIndicator -eq ==` limits the output to objects that compare equal, using [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax).
- Adding `-Recurse` to the [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) ensures that no confirmation prompt is shown if the target directory is non-empty; `-Force` ensures that removal succeeds even if the target directory is hidden or contains hidden items.